# useEffect and useState not setting value in fetch

Tags: react-native, fetch

i have a magazine style App, it has an index page which - is componente named HomeScreen - (with a list of articles) and a detail page - which is component named Details - (with the full article);
Over them i have a Home componente which is a Stack navigation for bot.

Home component

```
 const Home = ({}) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={HeaderOption} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Details"
        component={DetailsScreen}
        options={HeaderOption}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

then (same file) got the HomeScreen component which render (correctly) the list of articles, it uses useEffect to get them from an API

```
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [article, setArticles] = useState();
  const [loadingArticle, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('start Fetching');
    fetchTitles();
  }, []);
const fetchTitles = () => {
    fetch('myURL', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((responseData) => {
        setArticles(responseData);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };

  const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: Constants.HEIGTH,
        backgroundColor: Constants.MAIN_GREEN,
      }}
    >
      <LogoHeader title="TITOLO APP" isHome={true} navigation={navigation} />
      <View style={{ ...styles.container }}>
        <FlatList
          data={article}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate('Details', {
                  itemId: item.id,
                })
              }
            >
              <Card>
                <Card.Content>
                  <HTML
                    html={item.title.rendered}
                    baseFontStyle={{ fontSize: 20, color: '#adadad' }}
                  />

                  <Paragraph>
                    Published on {moment(item.date).format('LL')}
                  </Paragraph>
                </Card.Content>
                <Card.Cover source={{ uri: item.jetpack_featured_media_url }} />
                <Card.Content>
                  <HTML
                    html={item.excerpt.rendered}
                    imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get('window').width}
                  />
                </Card.Content>
              </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

When i click on the article i correctly reach Details with the correctly passed id but the singleArticle is 'null', even if responseData is correct:

```
 function DetailsScreen({ route, navigation }) {
      const { state } = useContext(AuthContext);
      const [singleArticle, setSingleArticle] = useState(null);
      const [loadingArticle, setLoadingSingle] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
       setLoadingSingle(true);
       console.log(loadingArticle); //return false (???)
        fetchSingle();
      }, []);
    
      const fetchSingle = () => {
        console.log('get_single');
        fetch(
          'myURLgetsingle?' +
            route.params.itemId,
    
          {
            method: 'GET',
          }
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
    
          .then((responseData) => {
            console.log('setting');
    
            console.log(responseData); //return the values i need
            setSingleArticle(responseData);
            console.log(singleArticle); //return null
          })
          .finally(() => setLoadingSingle(false));
      };
    
      console.log(singleArticle.title.rendered);
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            paddingTop: Constants.HEIGTH,
            backgroundColor: Constants.MAIN_GREEN,
          }}
        >
          <LogoHeader title="" isHome={false} navigation={navigation} />
          <Card style={{ ...styles.container, padding: 10 }}>
            <Card.Content>
              <Title>{singleArticle.title.rendered}</Title>
              <Paragraph></Paragraph>
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

i think im missing some basic use of react native, any way i can fix it up?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, this is totally normal with Hooks. When you call `setSingleArticle(responseData);` if you try to log `singleArticle` on next line is pretty much sure that you got a `null` value. This happens because `setSingleArticle` is async and, in Hooks, you **don't have** a callback like:

```
setSingleArticle(responseData, () => {
  // here I'm sure that singleArticle was setted
  // with Hooks this is impossible to do!
});
```

So the result is that in this line `console.log(singleArticle.title.rendered);` you should receive an error like "cannot get property title of null". Since your `singleArticle` value comes from a fetch, you could try to modify `singleArticle` default value like:

```
const [singleArticle, setSingleArticle] = useState({title: {rendered: ''}});
```

With this initalization `console.log(singleArticle.title.rendered);` does not fails. Same thing for this line `<Title>{singleArticle.title.rendered}</Title>`

**EDIT**

For a is-loading style you can do:

```
<Title>{singleArticle.title.rendered === '' ? "Loading..." : singleArticle.title.rendered}</Title>
```

Comment: that's perfectly fine that the set of useState are async, but in the main page (where i get the list of articles) they are always get with no miss, furthermore if they are async, how i can i realy on the is-loading style of useState? your suggestion looks ok and eliminate the error, but still the tile is empty on the detail page

Comment: If I undestood correctly you want to hide `<Title>{singleArticle.title.rendered}</Title>` showing for example "Loading..." until singleArticle will be setted, correct? Sorry, english is not my first language...

Comment: something like that and all the rest of the singleArticle object, i tried follow your approach and of course it no longer shows errors, but the title is never filled.
Details component is a copy of HomeScreen, but HomeScreen never fails.
also, if on my device i am on the Detail screen and from the code editor i save the file it seems that useState works, its like it works only first time (so if im on HomeScreen the list load, but subsequent calls do not work)

Comment: Ciao, that is strange (I mean when you say never filled). Initially is void (because of initialization), but when fetch returns value and you call setSingleArticle(responseData) ract should re-render <Text> with correct value. Can you show me output of console.log(responseData)?

Comment: yes, the content object starts with void and the loading object with true, the i fetch (and it fetch!) set the content object with the responseData object and at the endo of the fetch i use .finally(() => {
        setLoadingSingle(false);
        //console.log(singleArticle);
        //console.log(loadingSingleArticle);
      });

Comment: if i console.log(responseData.title.rendered); i got the correct value
the full singleArticle is a big object (https://www.popeating.it/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/6602)
and im sure it is correctly filled in responseData

Comment: Ciao, I updated my answer with the is-loading style. Let me know if could work.

Comment: Thank you! its starting to get in shape... i have to declare all the default values in setState i guess... they are probably hundreds :)

Comment: Eheheh, unfortunately it's the only way... Happy to have been helpful! Have a nice day :)